# Elixir Phoenix shutdown: failed to start child

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm getting the following error when starting my app in production mode. All works fine on dev side, can migrate, compile and release without issue on the production app but when running it, it crashes on start.
I'm sure it is something very obvious I am missing. I am running Erlang 19 and Elixir 1.3.2.

> 17:42:52.768 [info] Application curriculum exited:
>   Curriculum.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to
>   start child: Curriculum.Endpoint
>       ** (EXIT) shutdown: failed to start child: Phoenix.Endpoint.Server
>           ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
>               ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in System.get_env/1
>                   (elixir) lib/system.ex:358: System.get_env(4000)
>                   (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/server.ex:34: Phoenix.Endpoint.Server.to_port/1
>                   (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/server.ex:28: Phoenix.Endpoint.Server.default/3
>                   (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/server.ex:17: anonymous fn/5 in Phoenix.Endpoint.Server.init/1
>                   (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1623: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
>                   (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/server.ex:15: Phoenix.Endpoint.Server.init/1
>                   (stdlib) supervisor.erl:294: :supervisor.init/1
>                   (stdlib) gen_server.erl:328: :gen_server.init_it/6 {"Kernel pid
>   terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,curriculum,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Curriculum.Endpoint',{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Phoenix.Endpoint.Server',{function_clause,[{'Elixir.System',get_env,[4000],[{file,\"lib/system.ex\"},{line,358}]},{'Elixir.Phoenix.Endpoint.Server',to_port,1,[{file,\"lib/phoenix/endpoint/server.ex\"},{line,34}]},{'Elixir.Phoenix.Endpoint.Server',default,3,[{file,\"lib/phoenix/endpoint/server.ex\"},{line,28}]},{'Elixir.Phoenix.Endpoint.Server','-init/1-fun-0-',5,[{file,\"lib/phoenix/endpoint/server.ex\"},{line,17}]},{'Elixir.Enum','-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-',3,[{file,\"lib/enum.ex\"},{line,1623}]},{'Elixir.Phoenix.Endpoint.Server',init,1,[{file,\"lib/phoenix/endpoint/server.ex\"},{line,15}]},{supervisor,init,1,[{file,\"supervisor.erl\"},{line,294}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,328}]}]}}}}},{'Elixir.Curriculum',start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Prod.exs file contents

```
http: [port: {:system, 4000}],url: [host: "example.com"],cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json",server: true
config :phoenix, :serve_endpoints, true

import_config "prod.secret.exs"
```

Comment: Can you paste your `config/prod.exs`? Something seems wrong in the port config there.

Comment: Prod.exs contents added above, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value for `port` in `config/prod.exs` is wrong. It should either be:

```
port: 4000
```

to always run on port 4000, or:

```
port: {:system, "PORT"}
```

to read the port from the environment variable `PORT` (you can change the name to any other string).

Comment: Thank you very much